# Socket.io - delay when leaving a room

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I want to send the number of users connected to a room when a client leaves.

It seems `socket.leave()` has a delay.

How to do that properly? I don't like to use setTimeout()

```js
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  var roomsToSayGoodbye = io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id];
  for (var room in roomsToSayGoodbye) {
    io.sockets.in(room).clients().length; // For example: 6
    socket.leave(room);
    io.sockets.in(room).clients().length; // Still 6!!
    // So, this is wrong -->
    io.sockets.in(room).emit('nb-connections', { num: io.sockets.in(room).clients().length });
    // <--
    // and I need this to make it work, not clean! -->
    setTimeout(function() {
      io.sockets.in(room).clients().length; // Okay, now 5
    }, 1000 );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Socket.leave` is asynchronous, and as such has an optional second parameter for a callback, so you could do this:

```
socket.leave(room, function() {
    io.sockets.in(room).emit('nb-connections', { num: io.sockets.in(room).clients().length });
    // this should be the number you want
});
```

...which should report the correct number

This requires the latest version of Socket.io (version 1.0) which has not yet been published to npm (as of 11/14/2013).  To use it, you'd need to include the following in your package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "git://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io.git#1.0"
}
```

...which should pull in the 1.0 branch (caveat stability).

Comment: ( from the source code here https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/64f6b244b6bd79880ba2e0ba00778a2309b39d0b/lib/socket.js#L194 )

Comment: You are right, I thought about it. Reading the code show there is a callback: Socket.prototype.leave = function(room, fn).
But it doesnt work better + it shows a warning message: warn  - Client#leave callback is deprecated

Comment: In what way does it not work better?  Does it work? And what version of socket.io are you running?

Comment: I am running the latest stable on npm: 0.9.16. Reading the code shows that even using the callback, this callback calls other async methods, so the callback isn't triggered when the socket really left the room. 
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0.9/lib/socket.js#L185

Comment: Just updated the answer to reflect that the properly working version of the `room.leave` callback requires version 1.0, and how to inlcude that in your npm code.

Answer (score 0):

`io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]` returns a list of rooms with leading `'/'` character in all room names.

The [Socket.io Wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms) says : *"This is used internally and does not have to be referenced when joining, leaving or emitting to rooms."*

So, When you leave a room, make sure that the room name does not contain the leading `'/'` character. You can try `socket.leave(room.replace('/',''));`

Not tested, but should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't put all my code but I tested that. My code work (except for the delay) but leave() in asynchronous and call other asynchronous functions. It seems that it will be fixed in the version 1.0, but no idea about the release date.

Answer (score 0):

You can check working example of displaying number of clients in this repository. It is developed for socket.io v1.0 and express v4.0.

https://github.com/theoctal/livenote